# jquery datepicker steals click/focus event from inputfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

in the following code
http://jsfiddle.net/KRFCH/24/

```
<pre>
<input type="text" id="d" />
 <div id="z"></div>
```

pseudo code:

```
 $('#z').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  altField: '#d'
});

$('#d').change(function(){
    $('#z').datepicker('setDate', $(this).val());
});
$('#d').click();
$('#d').focus();
```

I can't get the input box to get the focus?
any ideas how I can make this happen?

Comment: I am using firefox 24.0 on linux. it doesnt work jsfiddle.net/KRFCH/27

Comment: Works in FF 24.0 on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Maybe try using the `showOn` option? Since I can't reproduce the problem, I can't tell whether it will help you.

Comment: I tried it now at home. the very first time I opened the url it worked and the inputfield had the focus. but then after a refresh or ctrl-enter I could not get the code working again....

Comment: I just click on the input field and start typing, and it works. I don't know what to tell you. Did you try `showOn: "button"`?

Answer (score 1):

just implement `onSelect` event handler:

```
$("#z").datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: '#d',
    onSelect: function () {
        this.focus();
    }
});
```